# C# Generic with limited return types

Tags: c#, generics

In C# I want to make some specialized generics that will be used just to return a specific type form another generic. The specialized generic's purpose is to force just some exact types that will be returned (like double, double[], byte, byte[]). Probably best is to explain by an example

```
var x = new MyGeneric<MyInterfaceDouble>();
double returnVal = x.getVal();

var x = new MyGeneric<MyInterfaceMyClass>();
MyClass returnVal = x.getVal();
```

So I have tried several ways to achieve this but unable to do so. Latest iteration is:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{}

public interface IMyInterface<T, U> :IMyInterface
{
    U getValue();
}

public class MyInterfaceDouble: IMyInterface<MyInterfaceDouble, double>, IMyInterface
{
    public double getValue()
    {
        return 8.355; 
    }
}

public class MyGeneric<T> where T : IMyInterface
{}
```

But I can't access the get value

```
var x = new MyGeneric<MyInterfaceDouble>();
double returnVal = x.getVal();   // not available
```

How can this be made?

Comment: Method not avaliable what do you mean, it doesnt exist? or is about protection level?, in your class definition your method is named: getValue, and you call getVal. that doesnt exist

Comment: @Ferus7 I believe the reason is that MyGeneric<T> does not inherit IMyInterface generic so it has no member. I have tried also by inheriting the non generic IMyInterfece but since it has no member will also not be avaliable.

Comment: `MyGeneric<T>` does not inherit `T`, nor does it implement any methods, so no, you're not going to find `getVal` or `getValue` on that object. Please clarify what you want to accomplish here because the language does not support what you're asking for here.

Comment: Nor will `MyGeneric<T>` magically inherit from `MyInterfaceDouble` if you pick something related to `double` for `T`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are going to have some changes in your design.

There is no any definiation for `getVal` inside `IMyInterface`, So is natural not available for `MyGeneric<MyInterfaceDouble>`.

You would inherit from `IMyInterface<T, U>` instead of `IMyInterface`:

```
public class MyGeneric<T> where T : IMyInterface<T, SomeSpecialType>
{}
```

**OR**

change `IMyInterface` defination to have `getVal` as general which returns `object`:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    object getValue();
}
```

**OR**

Change `MyGeneric<T>` definition to this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{ }

public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T getVal();
}

public class MyInterfaceDouble : IMyInterface<double>, IMyInterface
{
    public double getVal()
    {
        return 8.355;
    }
}

public class MyGeneric<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    T Obj { get; }
}
```

and use like this:

```
var x = new MyGeneric<MyInterfaceDouble>();
double returnVal = x.Obj.getVal();   // available
```

Also there are some other solutions which depends on your vision that you want to design.

Comment: If MyGeneric will inherit IMyInterface<T, SomeSpecialType> will not do. Second version: The return object will have to be casted afterwards.

Comment: The third version is so close. It's almost perfect. This also simplifies the specialized generics and interface